# Attempt to invoke virtual method in material dialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, dialog, material-design

I am using a library which can be found [HERE](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) to create material-design style dialog in an android app. I have made it so that the dialog opens when a FAB is clicked.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            final RatingBar mRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .title(R.string.title)
                    .positiveText(R.string.agree)
                    .negativeText(R.string.disagree)
                    .customView(R.layout.dialog_view, true)
                    .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) 
                            String sentReview = input.getText().toString();
                            float starCount = mRatingBar.getNumStars();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
```

The dialog successfully opens, and everything works well until I click the positive button "send". It then says "unfortunately DemoApp has stopped".

The exception is : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText() on a null object reference`.

The line that appears to be causing it is: `String sentReview = input.getText().toString();`.

If I comment the section which deals with the edit text and sent Review, the same problem will appear with my rating bar.

I have seen similar questions, but none of them precisely match my problem, and none of the methods they use work when I attempt to apply them to my application.

Thanks,

Geffen Avraham

Comment: `R.id.editText` is not being found in your layout. Have you set the content view? Is the id correct of your EditText?

Comment: ` <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />`

Comment: How do I set the content view?

Comment: In the Activity's OnCreate with `setContentView(R.layour.your_activity_layout);`. Just to check...have you done that?

Comment: yes. Well, R.layout, not R.layour :)

Comment: Ok. Dialog view is not my main activity, and I did not set it while accessing it. I solved my problem. However, editext.gettext returns empty.